# Distance between two points in the plane

Tags: geometry, contest-math, rational-numbers

my teacher asked in the class today the following question:
There exists an infinite set M of points in the plane with the property that any three points are non-collinear and such that the distance between any two points is a rational number?
Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be like $\;M\;$ had to be a circle-like set, but either the infinite condition or the rational distance one introduces an evil twist in this...

Comment: @DonAntonio I was thinking more along the lines of having an integer $x$-coord, with $y$-coord increasing more each time... then using pythag. triples or something.

Comment: @Mike, you can only have two different points with the same $\;x$-coordinate, since a third one already would give us three collinear points...and even then: how to tie down the condition about the rationality of the distances between **any** two points in the set??

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm suggesting one point for each (positive integer) $x$-coord. And yes, that's the issue. I've got no solution, just ideas :P

Comment: Oh, I see: one single point for each integer $\;x\;$ and different $\;y$-coordinates...which also no three of these points can have the same relation between the different coordinates lest they're collinear, e.g. $\;(1,2)\,,\,(2,4)\,,\,(-9,-18)\;$ ...

Comment: It is a standard result that there are. For example, let $M$ be the set of points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ such that $\tan(\theta/4)$ is rational. A not very easy result is that we cannot do it for integer distances.

Comment: I feel like this might be doable via induction -- I can easily find 3 points that match the criteria, but finding a fourth point is much harder -- if a method for adding another point can be found, than we're done

Comment: @andre-nicolas Could you please write up how $|\cos(\theta_1),\sin(\theta_1)),(\cos(\theta_2),\sin(\theta_2)|$ is rational if $\tan(\theta_1/4)$ and $\tan(\theta_2/4)$ are rational -- this does not seem obvious.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a set $M$. For example, let $M$ be the set of points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ such that $\tan(\theta/4)$ is rational. Since $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are rational functions of $\tan(x/2)$, it follows that for any two points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(\cos \phi,\sin\phi)$ in $M$, we have $\cos(\theta/2)$, $\sin(\theta/2)$, $\cos(\phi/2)$, $\sin(\phi/2)$ all rational.

The distance between the two points is $2|\sin(\theta-\phi)/2)|$. By the expression for the sine of a sum, this is rational.

**Remark:** The above argument can be found, among other places, in [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Anning_theorem)

It can be shown that if we have infinitely many points, with all distances *integers*, then the points must lie on a line.